# tracking changes in attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do have a problem with tracking changes in attributes
here is my model

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Generator  
  around_update :create_history
  def create_history    
    @event_status = "Status to #{self.status}.\n" if status_changed?    
    @event_owner = "Now it is provided by #{self.stuff.name}\n" if   stuff_id_changed?
    yield    
    histories.create(event: "Changed! #{@event_status} #{@event_owner} On #{self.updated_at.utc}") if @event_status || @event_owner
  end
end
```

action update is trivial

```
def update
   flash[:notice] = "Your ticket successfully updated."    
   @ticket.update!(ticket_params.merge(status: 0))    
end
```

But that does not work(specs on creating history fails. Im fighting with this for hours. Would be very grateful for any response pointing my mistake

Comment: you user `ticket_params.merge(status: 0)` so your `status` is always `0`. it doesn't change

Comment: also I would recommend to use [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem. it has very nice features for versioning your models.

Comment: and what about `stuff_id` values? is it really changed somehow?

Comment: You should post also the spec and the error it shows. "It fails" is not enough.

Comment: @Aleksey "paper_trail gem" make this an answer. One more question, in my task I need to track all the changes in my base model and show them to the user. Im a new guy in rails and web dev also. So to solve this I made a model history that has a string field as shown above and send each change through socket to histories page for user to see. Do you think it is enough? Or should I save the changes to exact fields. This is a test task so I am a bit confused - I dont need some ready answer just adwise.

Comment: if you would use paper_trail you would have `PaperTrail::Version` model with all history in there. see the gem README

Comment: why don't you create an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to say what is exactly wrong with your code.

One thing is `ticket_params.merge(status: 0)`. Since that your `status` is always `0` and never changed.

As long as I can't see `ticket_params` I can't say exactly what is wrong with `stuff_id` changes.

I created the same `around_update` callback in my test project and it works just fine.

The main thing I would like to notice that you should use [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem for dealing with your models history. The gem is awesome and you would really love it.